# Convert String to date in android

Tags: android

How to convert the string "Thu Jul 18 13:20:12 GMT+05:30 2013" in date in android?  Using DateFormatter and SimpleDateFormatter throw an exception saying cannot parse the date format while using it to convert into date.

Comment: Can you show us the code that you have written thus far?

Comment: using simple date format is the right way, just show us what you have done already.

Comment: just google it u will get may answers this is the URL http://androidadam.blogspot.in/2010/12/java-how-to-convert-string-to-date-and.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
    try {
        String dateString = "Thu Jul 18 13:20:12 GMT+05:30 2013";
        Date date = formatter.parse(dateString);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

this is how we doing in android..but if you can post your code then can help you precisely

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    String dateString = "Thu Jul 18 13:20:12 GMT+05:30 2013";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
    Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MM-YYYY");
Date dd = dateFormat.parse("string")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do:

```
try {
    String dateString = "Thu Jul 18 13:20:12 GMT+05:30 2013";

    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy").parse(dateString );
    }
    catch (ParseException e) 
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```